# how to make a button to sort alphabetically (what could be wrong)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm consuming the github api showing my repos, I made an input to search the repos and it's ok
my problem is when I made a button to sort from A-Z it just doesn't do anything, what could I have done wrong??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mu3f.png)

Comment: Put the code in the question, not an image of code.

Comment: You can try changing 'ev.target' to 'ev.target.value' in onSearchChangeValue function.

Comment: is repos part of your state (useState) ?

Comment: repos should be a state variable, if you just update a variable which is not defined with useState this won't enforce a new execution of the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is basically doing nothing since it's calling a function that sorts an array, then returns it. But you're not doing anything with that sorted array.

Try changing it to something like this:

```
const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]) // This is your state

...

<button onClick={() => {setRepos(sortedListRepo())}}>Sort</button>
```